# Find a Javascript ID when trying to deregister?

Tags: functions

I am trying to remove a plugin from loading on a specific page.

This is the idea I have to do it:

```
//Remove plugin Javascript
function de_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'name-javascript-1' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'name-javascript-2' );
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'de_script', 100 );
```

Problem is that when I view the source of the page there is no ID like there is for CSS?

Any ideas how to do this when the Javascript does not have an ID?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you search through the plugin's files? Searching for `wp_enqueue_script` should get you those handles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a global variable `$wp_scripts`, so pop this in a PHP template and have a look:

```
global $wp_scripts;
print_r($wp_scripts);
```

Found it in the Source section of the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_print_scripts/) entry for `wp_print_scripts`, btw - always a good place to look!